Compile and Run dynamic C++ code inside react native app
I have a react native application for android, where i want to give user the capability of writing c++ code inside a code editor and then compiling and executing to show the output. I don't want to use a external service or server for compiling code as I don't have any platform where I can deploy production ready server without read-only environment at free of cost. There are some platforms that offer deploying with limited resources for free but I want a permanent solution free of cost. So that's why I want to execute it within the app itself.
Since I am not sure about how to achieve this inside react native app, can someone give me a step by step process on how to achieve this? I came across a solution of using NDK and clang but not sure how should I do it.

The Android Store T&Cs specifically disallow this as it would allow self modifying code, bypassing virus and malware scans done by the Play Store.  That's why apps use external services / websites.  There are apps that can be side-loaded that do this (some also need root).

The reason for the "read-only environment" is that otherwise one of the first users will erase all your files. Just for "fun". And then upload and compile their spam-bot, using your id for all the messages.

Termux ships Clang for android, copy what they do.

One option would be to use webassembly (that also fullfils the sandboxing requirement for the Android Store T&Cs) (see react-native-webassembly). There are a few packages you could use that bundle clang as a wasm module: emception (live example) or the wasmer clang/clang package (example), etc...

Do keep in mind that this will massively increase your app size - clang is not a small binary - in addition to that you also need to bundle the standard library, a linker, all C++ headers, and a lot of other stuff to actually build anything useful — if you go the wasm route then expect your app size to increase by 100MB+; without wasm it'd be even worse because you need to package clang separately for each architecture you want to support (armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64, etc...)
